# How can I get FusionCharts initiallyHidden attribute to work?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I have a chart that is reloaded periodically, and I'd like to ensure that the series that the user has hidden (by clicking on their legend names) remain hidden. I tried setting the series initiallyHidden attribute to a saved value on reload, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Using the following line, I set the attribute in the AJAX callback that is used to get the current data and load it into the chart:

```
widget.ChartData.dataset[seriesIndex].initiallyHidden = widget.settings.initiallyHidden[seriesIndex];
```

`widget.settings.initiallyHidden[seriesIndex]` is the value that is saved by my event handler when the user clicks on the legend name, and even when it is "1", the series still becomes visible.

Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried an experiment where I set the initiallyHidden attribute to "1" initially, and it still did not work. We're currently using FusionCharts 3.3.1-sr2, and I did not find any evidence of that attribute in the docs until 3.4.0, so I'm guessing that my failure to get it to work is that we need to upgrade the charting package.

Comment: Not sure, which chart you are using. Have you consider / tried the realtime charts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `visible = "0"`. For the old versions I tried to use the `initiallyHidden` attribute but, it did not work. You also need to render using javascript.